# Edo era manga with a businessman and girl who can both read thoughts?

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is basically a love manga in which a businessman can hear thoughts. I'm pretty sure he will marry a girl that can read thoughts but she isn't educated.

If I'm not wrong this was set in the Edo Period.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be *[Kimi no Koe](https://myanimelist.net/manga/131242/Kimi_no_Koe)* (*Beyond You*)?

> **Kazunari Kyougoku is the boss of an up-and-coming trading company in
> the Taishou era.** With his unparalleled negotiation skills to close
> every deal he sets his eyes on, he has started to gain popularity
> among his competition. Yet despite this momentum, his success was not
> earned through bargaining alone—he possesses the ability to hear other
> people's thoughts. This power has allowed him to see through the lies
> of many, causing him to distrust others.
>
> Wishing to bring even more prosperity to his business, Kazunari plans
> on marrying the daughter of the noble Suwabe family. His proposal is
> accepted, and he soon learns something about his future bride. The
> daughter, Nana Suwabe, is unable to speak. With this information,
> **Kazunari is delighted to know that he will only have to hear Nana's
> inner voice.**
>
> However, upon meeting her, he quickly realizes that he is unable to
> hear her thoughts. Having lived his entire life hearing the intentions
> of others, Kazunari endeavors to slowly understand his partner's true
> feelings and discover a harmonious future together.
>
> [image]

Comment: Could you add an image description of where in the manga the image is from?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - About three pages into the first chapter, if memory serves. Finding it shouldn't be a problem.